# Raspberry Pi 4 not booting constant red light and different green light patterns at random times

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, boot-issues

## Issue

When the pi boots 9/10 times it goes as follows:

- Constant red light
- Green light flashes fast three times and the fourth flash does 4 - 5 extremely fast small flashes and repeats

On the very odd 1/10 times it goes as follows:

- Constant red light
- Green light flashes slowly three times and the fourth time it stays green for a decent time (3 seconds roughly)

*(Currently unable to get it to replicate the 1/10 scenario)*

--

## What I have tried

So I have tried almost everything that I can find online about fixing a raspberry pi that does not boot. I have tried

1. Using Noobs, Rasbian and multiple light linux distros
2. Editing the config file and turning the two hdmi comments into code by deleting the hashtag
3. Running mini HDMI and (currently) USB to VGA and multiple different VGA cables
4. Two SD cards formatted as (currently) FAT32 and exfat
5. Downloading the official files on the raspberry site that supposed to fix some corrupt part and still nothing

It was running for a few months and everyhing was fine but then my dad found a alternative to the current set up we had so put the pi in storage and now I am unable to revive it. We were running Linux Mint with no issues at all and it was in the case at all times.

Comment: Pi 4 needs a beefy stable PSU; is yours those things?

Comment: The one I previously used worked like a charm so it should do so now I assume

Comment: Its a 5.0v output PSU, also says "= 700ma" next to the voltage number

Comment: No good. The official Raspberry Pi 4 power supply is rated at 5.1 v 3 amps, which is 3,000 mA. That 700 mA thing sounds like some kind of cheap phone charger. Unlike some earlier Pis, the Pi 4 will not be happy with any old phone charger you have lying around.

Comment: Do you have any idea to why it worked for such a long time though? Also thank you, I will purchase a 5.1v one!

Comment: PSU could have gone bad

Comment: Please note the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)